# Create an XML file Batch

Tags: batch, xml

So, I want to include in one of my batch file projects a way to create an XML file. I already have a way of parseing XML files to get the data out of them, so that is of no matter. Anyways.

Let's say I have 3 variables. One called package, another package-ver and lastly one called package-url.

I want them to be created into an XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <package-info>
      <package data="%package%">
      <package-ver data="%package-ver%">
      <package-url data="%package-url%">
   </package-info>
```

I would then preceed to have this be pipped into a text file. But, I don't want to have to tell it to do this every single time, how can I have it so I can give, let's say a function or program input and it'll create all of this for me.

How would I do this?

-- EDIT -- 
Added other two variables, sorry.

Comment: 1) I see only a single variable in your XML, where are the other two? 2) What do you want to do exactly? Pass three strings as command line arguments to a batch file and have it generate an XML with those strings inserted at the appropriate locations?

Comment: Have you googled your question already? look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16841557/2098699)

Comment: @Karan, That's exactly what I'm trying to do. 3 vartiables that are then put into the associated locations in an xml file, as you stated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `%1`, `%2`, `%3`, etc. to select the command line arguments and ^ to escape characters.

Example: call this batch file with the arguments `batch.bat <package> <package-ver> <package-url> <path to output file>`. It will output to the specified file (but without linebreaks, that can be done by encapsulating the `echo` command in parentheses combined with using `&&` and `echo.`)

```
@echo off
echo ^<?xml version="1.0"?^>^<package-info^>^<package data="%1"^>^<package-ver data="%2"^>^<package-url data="%3"^>^</package-info^> > %4
```